# The probability of the union of complements of two events

Tags: probability

We have:

- 5 men older than 21
- 4 men younger than 21
- 6 women older than 21
- 3 women younger than 21.

We have events;

- A = $\{$the person taken is older than 21$\}$
- B = $\{$the person taken is younger that 21$\}$
- C = $\{$the person taken is a man$\}$
- D = $\{$the person taken is a woman$\}$

> Calculate the probability  $P(A^c \cup C^c)$.

I started saying that $$P(A^c \cup C^c) = 1 - P(A \cap C),$$ but $$P(A \cap C)=\dfrac{5}{18},$$ because the intersection of A and C consist of the 5 men older than 21, so $$P(A^c \cup C^c)=\dfrac{13}{18}.$$

BUT I checked the answer in the book and it says that the correct answer is $\dfrac{1}{6}$!! And that bugs me because I don´t know if I´m wrong or is an errata of the book.

Can you tell me please if I´m right or if I have made a mistake in an earlier step?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}\left(A^c \cup B^c\right) = 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B\right)$, and not with $\mathbb{P}\left(A \cap C\right)$.

Comment: My mistake, it is well written now, thanks.

Comment: You're right, the book is wrong. It happens sometimes. (Unless the book actually said $P(A^C\cap C^C)$ with $\cap$ rather than $\cup$; your answer is correct for the $\cup$ problem but the book's answer is correct for the $\cap$ problem.)

Comment: Maybe $A^c\cup C^c$ was a typo for $A^c\cap C^c$.